# Sitecore MVC and FieldRenderer.Render for Links

Tags: hyperlink, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I'm trying to render a general link field like this - `FieldRenderer.Render(item, "link")`.

This works as expected but how do I set custom text within the a tag that gets rendered. I want my output to look something like this

```
<a href="[link from sitecore]">[custom text from another field]</a>
```

Basically, the text for the link should come from another field on the item.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to try the following:

```
@Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Link Field")
//custom code
@Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```

Comment: Is there any reference for the MVC api?

Answer (score 10):

Jason has a great idea, but this functionality is out of the box.

```
@Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Link Field", new { haschildren= true })
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Text Field")
@Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```

No need to modify anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

Varun's answer is definitely correct, however you will encounter an issue when the content editor has put a value into the `Description` field of a `General Link`. The link renderer will output both the description and whatever is between the `BeginField` and `EndField` methods.

A solution would be to allow for an extra parameter (`HideDescription`) which can hide the description. Two possible solutions for this would be;

1. Override the standard `Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.LinkRenderer` class with your own that would stop the description from being put in.
2. Add a custom pipeline step after the `Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetLinkFieldValue` which will do some post rendered processing to remove the description.

Option 2 is less invasive but is a little more difficult to make sure the results are 100%. Once you have this you can then render fields like the following;

```
@Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Link Field", new { HideDescription = true })
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Text Field")
@Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```

Answer (score 1):

already has been answered but this worked for me

```
@Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Target URL", item.InnerItem, new { text = @Html.Sitecore().Field("Title", item.InnerItem) })

@Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use begin and end-field and use the haschildren property, this will hide the text and just display any child-content between the begin and end statements:

```
@Html.Sitecore().BeginField("ItemName/ID", Model.DataSourceItem, new {
  haschildren = true,
  @class = "my-custom-class"
})
<span class="extra-content">
  @Html.Sitecore().Field("Text Field")
</span>
@Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```