# In Sitecore output a link tag in View

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

In Sitecore I have a controller rendering, which dynamically loops through all of the navigation bar items in the Multi-list and outputs them out to the View.

I have tried the code below:

```
<li class="first-child"><a href="@i.Url">@i.Name</a></li>
```

However, when I do inspect element in the Browser this appears:

```
<a href="<link linktype="external"; url="";https://www.example.com/en-gb/london/eat"; anchor="" target="" />">Eat</a>
```

The above line produces an additional > before Eat. What do I have to

I have also tried this syntax in the View:

```
<li class="first-child">
    <a href="@Html.Sitecore().Field("Url", i);">
             @Html.Sitecore().Field("Name", i);
    </a>
</li>
```

When I inspect element in the Browser I get this:

```
<a href=";"> ; </a>
```

I need help rendering this in the View any help with the syntax will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

My Controller action method looks like this below:

```cs
public ActionResult FooterCities() 
{

    var model = new List<FooterCities>();

    var footercitycategories = Sitecore.Context.Item;

    var item = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField)footercitycategories.Fields["FooterCities"];

    foreach (var m in item.GetItems())
    {
        model.Add(
        new FooterCities()
        {
            Name = m["Name"],
            CityUrl = m["CityUrl"]
        });

    }

    return View("/Views/Example/Layouts/LayoutRenderings/ViewRendering/FooterCities.cshtml", model);

}
```

Comment: Is this what you need? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32848931/157833

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sitecore MVC and FieldRenderer.Render for Links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958601/sitecore-mvc-and-fieldrenderer-render-for-links)

Comment: i is  @foreach(var i in Model)

Comment: and what is the type of your `Model`?

Comment: wow, you are making this difficult... what type of c# class?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Url", new { haschildren= true })
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Name")
@Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```

Code above copied from another SO answer explaining how to use text field inside a link field here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32848931/157833 .

or another option:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Url", new {text = @Html.Sitecore().Field("Name")})
```

explained by Jason here: https://theagilecoder.wordpress.com/2014/10/06/sitecore-mvc-editable-links-wrapping-text-and-images/

Assuming that you're `i` is an object of the `Item` class, you should pass it as a second parameter. Method definition is:

```cs
public virtual HtmlString Field(string fieldName, Item item, object parameters)
```

so in your case it should be:

```cs
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Url", i, new {text = @Html.Sitecore().Field("Name")})
```

---

**EDIT** after you showed code of your controller

You should change the way of model generation. Use:

```cs
foreach (var m in item.GetItems())
{
    Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField urlField = m.Fields["CityUrl"];
    string url = urlField.GetFriendlyUrl();
    model.Add(
    new FooterCities()
    {
        Name = m["Name"],
        CityUrl = url
    });
}
```

and then in the view:

```
<li class="first-child">
    <a href="i.CityUrl">
        i.Name
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: @Liam my intention was not to copy someone else's answer and pretend it's mine. It's 3 line of code you'll find in 90% of Sitecore MVC projects. Check https://www.google.pl/search?q="%40Html.Sitecore().BeginField" . And I do think those questions are different despite that fact that the answer for them is the same.

Comment: Hi Marek, I tried to implement both of your samples, it has not worked at the moment. I am outputting the text dynamically through a for loop                          **@foreach(var i in Model) {** I am passing i as an obj parameter like this:  **@Html.Sitecore().Field("Url", new {text = @Html.Sitecore().Field("Name")}, i)**  In the browser the View is empty

Comment: Assuming that `i` is object of the `Item` class, you should pass it as the second parameter. Method definition is `public virtual HtmlString Field(string fieldName, Item item, object parameters)`

Comment: Hi Marek, I still get an error are there any **using** imports that I have to add into the page?

Comment: I did some debugging and in the controller action method. I made a simple model called FooterCities. Which contains two properties the **Url** and the **Name**. I returned this to the View, rather that the Item. Which is what I think is causing the problem. I will show you my action method above, for rendering the View above.

Comment: I did a quick check, and the only thing that didi not work was the : GetFriendlyUrl(). Is GetFriendlyUrl part of GlassMapper. Is it possible to do this part without using GlassMapper?